# Given Nd6, what is the probability that the two highest are minimum 4?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, dice

So, my statistics knowledge is rather poor, so I would welcome a formula explanation to the question:
given Nd6 (6-sided dice) what is the probability that the two highest numbers are at least a 4?

Given 2d6, i think it's 6/21, though i shamefully admit reaching it by (possibly faulty) enumeration.

Comment: Your calculation for 2d6 should be $\frac14$ (as @ajotatxe's answer shows). I'm guessing that you got $\frac{6}{21}$ from counting the pairs $(1,1), (1,2), \ldots, (6,6)$, but that you only counted $(1,2)$ and not $(2,1)$, etc. You have to count all $36$ possibilities, and of those, there are $9$ good ones: $(4,4), (4,5), (4,6), (5,4), \ldots, (6,6)$. Thus $\frac{9}{36} = \frac14$.

Comment: good thing i added the 'possibly faulty' line. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The probability to get at least a four in one die is $1/2$. Therefore, the probability to get three or less in $N$ throws is
$$\frac1{2^N}$$
and the probability to get a four or more in exactly one throw is
$$\frac N{2^N}$$
The $N$ comes from the fact that the "good throw" can be the first, the second, ..., or the $N$-th.

Thus, the probability to get four or more in two or more dices is $1$ minus the sum of the previous probabilities:
$$1-\frac1{2^N}-\frac N{2^N}=\frac{2^N-N-1}{2^N}$$